# No puedo acceder al ultimo dato de un array dinamico

Tags: javascript, json, array, react-native

Estoy tratando de acceder al ultimo dato de un array dinamico creado a partir de una petición a una API para mi app creada en react native, para tratar de acceder a ese dato, hago uso de **Array.lenght**, esto funciona solo en arrays de 2 datos, pero cuando el array es de 3 o mas datos, solo accede al 2 dato.

```
<FlatList
    data={cities}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Card style={styles.list}>
            <CardItem bordered>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    setCity(item['structured_formatting']['main_text'])
                    setCountry(item['terms'][Array.length]['value'])
                }}>
                    <Text>{item['structured_formatting']['main_text']}, {item['terms'][Array.length]['value']}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </CardItem>
        </Card>
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener en cuenta que los índices del array van desde cero, si por ejemplo tienes 2 elementos el primer elemento se encontrará en la posición *a[0]* y el segundo elemento en la posición *a[1]*. Si intentas acceder al último elemento del array con la propiedad length, estarás accediendo *a[2]*, esto se debe a que array.length devuelve el número de elementos contados desde 1.

Dado esta implementación debes siempre restar menos uno al tamaño del array.

```
let ultimaPos = array[array.length - 1];
```

Ahora bien, siempre te va tomar el segundo elemento dado que estas accediendo mediante Array.length y este siempre tiene como valor estatico 1, deberias utilizar la misma instancia del arreglo dinamico para acceder al indice, es decir tu codigo deberia quedar:

```
item['terms'][items.length - 1]['value']
```

con esto tomarías el ultimo objeto del `items`, y no de `Array.length`

Comment: Disculpa, el objeto items no existe por lo que debería ser: item['terms'][item.length - 1]['value']